# shell how to find last entry in /etc/passwd

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am trying to write my own shell script to add a user in Linux. I don´t want to use useradd. So how to I find the last entry in passwd ? I would like to check the USER ID, and GROUP ID. So i can make +1 to UISER ID and +1 Group ID.

Or is there any possibility to make a grep on the last entry in a file?

e.G.

```
simpson:x:103:103:Lisa Simpson, etc...
```

Comment: Hope you won't use it any production system. Editing /etc/passwd manually is just wrong (given that a system might not use it at all and use, for example, LDAP instead), and generating new user ID by adding +1 to last entry in that file is plainly outrageous - at the very least there's a of system/regular users, there's no guarantee that the last entry in the file would have maximum possible ID in a given category, etc, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use tail:

```
tail -1 /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 0):

With sed:

```
sed -n '$'p /etc/passwd
```

http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#tail